# Running multiple threads in Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I need to execute parallel tasks in a Java application. Right now, I have a java class that implements a `Callable<DMI>`, where DMI is an object that I use in a JSF bean.

The problem is that all Callable objects are running in the same thread, then only after a complete execution of all of them, the thread changes. I want to run every object on a different thread. What am I doing wrong?

**Class Callable**

```
 public class ModuloCallable implements Callable<DMI> {

    private final String NOME;
    private final String URL;

    public ModuloCallable(String nome, String url) {
        this.NOME = nome;
        this.URL = url;
    }

    @Override
    public DMI call() {

        try {   

                /* Some code here to generate a DMI object */

                System.out.println("Thread number: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                return dmi;

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {                

            return null;

        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

**Java application**

```
public void buscar() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ModuloCallable G1C = new ModuloCallable("n1", "url1") 
        ModuloCallable G2C = new ModuloCallable("n2","url2");
        ModuloCallable G3C = new ModuloCallable("n3","url3");
        DMI geradorG1 = getFutureValue(G1C, executor);
        DMI geradorG2 = getFutureValue(G2C, executor);
        DMI geradorG3 = getFutureValue(G3C, executor);
        executor.shutdown();
    }
   public DMI getFutureValue(ModuloCallable mc, ExecutorService e) {
        Future<DMI> f = e.submit(mc);
        DMI dmi;
        try {
            dmi = f.get();
            return dmi;
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of output**

```
Thread number: 150
Thread number: 150
Thread number: 150
```

If i call the buscar method multiple times in sequence, than i would have something like:

```
Thread number: 150
Thread number: 150
Thread number: 150
Thread number: 151
Thread number: 151
Thread number: 151
```

I want something like:

```
Thread number: 148
Thread number: 149
Thread number: 150
```

Comment: You are doing `submit` immediately followed by a `get` three times which is non-parallel and basically completely single-threaded. Do your three submits, get your Futures, then do the three gets.

Comment: @clay Thank you! It was a simple thing after all.